# Why isn't there a Facebook Sign-In tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags

Recently I asked a question on Stack Overflow and I was wondering why is there no [facebook-signin] tag if there is a [google-signin] tag. Even if there wasn't a Google Sign-In tag, we would need the [facebook-signin].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably because we have a [facebook-login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-login) tag, and "Facebook Login" [is the wording used by Facebook itself](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login).

[facebook-signin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-signin) might make a decent tag synonym though.

Comment: Wow... I didn't know there was. Thanks.